# What if Rollback statement calls without specifying a save point

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We can create savepoints in Oracle and then we can rollback to a specific savepoint by calling the `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT <savepoint_name>`.

```
UPDATE employees 
    SET salary = 7000 
    WHERE last_name = 'Banda';
SAVEPOINT banda_sal;

UPDATE employees 
    SET salary = 12000 
    WHERE last_name = 'Greene';
SAVEPOINT greene_sal;

SELECT SUM(salary) FROM employees;

ROLLBACK; --> the rollback without the savepoint

UPDATE employees 
    SET salary = 11000 
    WHERE last_name = 'Greene';

COMMIT;
```

Can someone explain how the above code works?

At once this can be seen as a silly question. But there can be scenarios where it is difficult to identify where the ROLLBACK statement are executed in a complex PL SQL program (if you have to do only a modification to the existing code).

Comment: [From the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9023.htm#SQLRF01610) "*If you omit the savepoint clause, then the ROLLBACK statement rolls back the entire transaction*"

Comment: The `ROLLBACK` undoes everything until the last `COMMIT`.

Comment: You can always trace your session and find the rollback points (XCTEND rlbk=1) but this can get complex if you are making calls to uncommitted procs/packages within your plsql blocks.

Comment: @Tenzin, provided you did only DML's. Each DDL makes an automatic COMMIT.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - What Tenzin said is 100% correct, but perhaps too terse. What you added is valuable, but it does not contradict what Tenzin said. An automatic `COMMIT` is, obviously, a `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't use "savepoint to" `rollback` will rolls back to enter point(in your example it is `first update`,because your transaction is starting from `first update`), after `rollback` if you are using some `DML`(in your example `third update`) finally "commit"  will be commit  only last part of your transaction (after last rollback part,  `third update`)

```
--- start transactions

UPDATE employees 
    SET salary = 7000 
    WHERE last_name = 'Banda';
SAVEPOINT banda_sal;

UPDATE employees 
    SET salary = 12000 
    WHERE last_name = 'Greene';
SAVEPOINT greene_sal;

SELECT SUM(salary) FROM employees;

ROLLBACK; -- roolback to first DML("start transactions" part,because there  is no any savepoint to)

UPDATE employees 
    SET salary = 11000 
    WHERE last_name = 'Greene';

COMMIT;  -- commit only last update
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding this comment:

> But there can be scenarios where it is difficult to identify where the ROLLBACK statement are executed in a complex PL SQL program (if you have to do only a modification to the existing code).

If you are running an Oracle Database 12c Release 2 instance (available now for download from OTN, Github and Docker, or multiple cloud services), you can take advantage of PL/Scope to find all the places in your code where commits and rollbacks are executed (PL/Scope was first added in 11.1, but analysis of SQL statements was added in 12.2):

You must first enable gathering of scope data:

```
ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='identifiers:all, statements:all'
```

Then when you compile program units, information is put into ALL_IDENTIFIERS (PL/SQL statements) and ALL_STATEMENTS (SQL statements, new to 12.2).

Once you have done that, the following queries will locate all commits and rollbacks:

```
SELECT st.owner,
       st.object_name,
       st.object_type,
       st.line,
       src.text
  FROM all_statements st, all_source src
 WHERE     st.TYPE = 'COMMIT'
       AND st.object_name = src.name
       AND st.owner = src.owner
       AND st.line = src.line
ORDER BY st.owner,
         st.object_name,
         st.object_type   
/

SELECT st.owner,
       st.object_name,
       st.object_type,
       st.line,
       src.text
  FROM all_statements st, all_source src
 WHERE     st.TYPE = 'ROLLBACK'
       AND st.object_name = src.name
       AND st.owner = src.owner
       AND st.line = src.line
ORDER BY st.owner,
         st.object_name,
         st.object_type    
/
```

You can find lots more information about and examples for PL/Scope [here](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/search?q=pl%2Fscope).